# Rewriting url and htaccess (localhost)

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, localhost

I'm learning a tutorial in order to rewrite the url of my posts (ex: **articles/presentation-et-demonstration-des-jeux-videos-a-venir-pour-l-annee-2018-516** instead of **articles.php?billet=516presentation-et-demonstration-des-jeux-videos-a-venir-pour-l-annee-2018**) but I'm receiving an error statement in local with the following message :

> This page isn't working
>
> localhost redirect too many times.
>
> Try to delete cookies..
>
> ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

By my side,  php.ini and httpd.conf are set to be use properly.
Furthermore, I've deleted cookies in my navigator.

This is the code I'm using in my .htaccess which I put in the good root :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule articles/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)-([0-9]+) articles.php?id=$2 [L]
```

Could someone please give me a hand with this trouble ?

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Go disable MultiViews ...

Comment: Could you please tell me how should I disable MultiViews ?

Answer (score 0):

it's not .htaccess error or .htaccess misswriting

this error

> This page isn't working
>
> localhost redirect too many times.

maybe happend cause the site always read `header('location: url');` or `window.location.href` in javascript to the same **direction/url**.

like if you use `header('location: index.php')` in file **index.php** that mean everytime you **read/open index.php** you will be **directed** to the **index.php** and when you **read/open** again it will make you being **redirected** again. So the server prevent this with this **error**.

**NOTE**

Make sure you use `header('location: url')` correctly if you use it, since the **.htaccess** file make everything **redirected** throught **article.php** check if there was any **redirecting function** in your **code**.